# What is the common procedure for rotating DKIM keys?

Tags: dkim

I am looking for roughly how to generate new DKIM keys without effecting existing mail.  It sounds like the only concern is mail in transit.  Is there a common procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would generate a new key pair. Publish it in a new new selector._domainkey.example.com.
Wait for the new selector to propagate in DNS.
Update your e-mail system to use the new selector.
After a week or so, remove the old selector DNS record.